# Why do we need org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 in selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

Is there any specific reason why we use `GridlauncherV3`, Currently doing a project where I use custom servlets for executing some task

For launching node:

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver -cp testservlet.jar:selenium-server-standalone.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 -role node -maxSession 10 -port 4444 -host localhost -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,version=103,platform=LINUX,maxInstances=10 -servlets testservlet.copies.DemoServlet,testservlet.copies.Demo2Servlet
```

Couldn't find any reason but if removed it throws an error, Were it needs a params

```
Unrecognized option: -role
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using `java -cp`, it is a requirement to specify the class that contains the main() method.

In the case of creating a `jvm` to run as `selenium grid`, you require the class that contains the main() method, in this case that is `org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3`.

This method is used to initiate the grid with all the required configuration in your cli command.

See the method here: [GridLauncherV3](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/selenium-3.141.59/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/selenium/GridLauncherV3.java)

Comment: Thanks well explained, So when i use "-jar" does manifest know main() path?